# What Cocoa class is this?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

Can somebody please tell me which class/IB widget this is for the headers where it says "Task", "Grade", "Files"?

[image: Inspector window with collapsible sections]

Thanks.

EDIT: My question was totally unclear. Let me rephrase. This is a screenshot from an app called ["Schoolhouse"](http://www.schoolhouseapp.com/). I was wondering how I can get that same style for the headers (headers being where it says "Task", "Grade", "Files"). Basically, what did he use to make this layout?

Comment: I'm no cocoa guru but this question isn't clear - could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [InspectorKit](http://www.degutis.org/dev/open-source/2009/03/09/introducing-inspectorkit/). You may be interested in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260272/cocoa-interface-builders-attributes-inspector-like-window).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has installed an InterfaceBuilder plugin to add custom views in it.

If you use the inspector you should be able to see what name the class has, and hopefully can from it find the header file needed to access this thing in code.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100109-q48mdui66s77yy6i8mu5s45gu5.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100109-q48mdui66s77yy6i8mu5s45gu5.jpg)

### Edit

Well, to create an inspector pane you can also have a look at [OmniGroups open source frameworks](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/)